# Unable to access elements of pdf viewer in a shadow host with Cypress

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests, cypress, shadow-dom

I am trying to access the value of "original-url". It appears to be in a "shadow host" but I have tried every syntax I can think of with no success. Attached below the code are some screenshots, thanks in advance for any guidance!

EDIT: I think it has something to do with the part of the page being a modal, or that somehow cypress is not seeing the part of the page containing the pdf

```
//snippet of the cypress code
context('Test',{ includeShadowDom: true }, () => {
    before(() => {
        cy.login();
    });

it('downloads the generated pdf form', { includeShadowDom: true }, () => {
    
        cy.get('.viewer').shadow().find('original-url').then(($pdfDest) => {
            
            const pdfUrl = $pdfDest.text()

            cy.downloadFile(pdfUrl, '/genPdfs/', genPdf.pdf)

        })
    })
```

//the element on the page using inspect

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" original-url="blob:https://somewebsite.com/fbe361d4-9393-e8bc728d8b9c#toolbar=0&amp;view=fitH" src="chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/2bf57493-fbe8-499f-9437-6d42267ac53d" background-color="4283586137" javascript="allow" top-level-url="https://somewebsite.com/__/#/tests/integration/specialized/Test.spec.js" pdf-viewer-update-enabled="">
```

Inspection of the page:
[image: inspection of the page]

Example cypress error:
[image: example cypress error]
same cypress error using #
[image: second cypress error]

Answer (score 0):

Your `pdf-viewer` element that contains shadow root has a "viewer" id, not a class.

So try `cy.get('#viewer').shadow()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I just tried that and it doesn't find that either. Any other ideas?

Comment: What's the error you get now? If the error is that element "orginal-url" cannot be found then you again have the same problem, you're using incorrect selector. I would suggest to get familiar with how selectors work here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Selector

Comment: You would probably need something like `.find('[orginal-url]')` but it's way better if you share the exact error so that we don't have to guess.